# do PHPUnit tests need to be inside a "/test" directory?

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

when using PHPUnit, is it required for tests to be inside of a /tests directory? How does PHPUnit know that a test is a "test"? Does it parse the file and look for method names, or use some sort of naming convention of files?

Answer (score 6):

> it required for tests to be inside of a /tests directory?

No.

> How does PHPUnit know that a test is a "test"?

Via reflection (and by the user specifying a directory to look into).

Comment: Sure, the documentation tells you how to start the testrunner and explains it's parameters, it specifies how tests need to be written: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/index.html - additional information is available in the sourcecode of PHPUnit itself: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/

Answer (score 4):

> Does it parse the file and look for method names, or use some sort of naming convention of files?

- [If first checks if the passed argument is a file](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php#L521) so you could call `phpunit myTestStuff.php`
- Since it's not in your case [It recursively scans the directory](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php#L141) by [calling File_Iterator](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php#L90) and adding all files that [end in "Test.php" and ".phpt" to your testsuite.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php#L91)
- [It then goes through all those files](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php#L343) and adds all the [classes that extend from `PHPUnit_Framework_Test`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php#L391)
- Then the tests are run

So in short:

Filename needs to end in `Test.php`, class needs to extends from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (some point down the inheritance tree).

It is good practice to seperate your test code from your production code though. Usually it mirrors the folder structure. But there is nothing stopping you from doing it differently. Just consider that it's easier to generate statistics (metrics) for your production code.

Maybe you want to have some automatically checked coding rules for your production code and others for your tests.

You want to generate code coverage for your code and have it include all the production code but not all the tests. (PHPUnit will not show your test classes in the coverage anyways but base and helper classes)

Answer (score 2):

Convention is to name the test classes and files by appending `Test` to those of the classes you're testing. For example `My_Cool_User` in `My/Cool/User.php` would be tested with `My_Cool_UserTest` in `My/Cool/UserTest.php`.

I prefer to separate the tests in their own directory, but this isn't required. By using a naming convention you can tell PHPUnit how to find all the tests mixed in with your regular code. By default PHPUnit follows the above, so if you point it to a folder called `myproject` it will look for all files ending in `Test.php` within it.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your settings and directories, and select and verify your test and source locations are added.